# Object Oriented Database: N:M Relations

Tags: c#, database, object

I'm working on a project and this is just confusing me to no end. I have 2 tables, Movies (filmes) and Actors (atores) and a movie has a lot of actors and vice-versa, actors have a lot of movies.

I declared each table as follows:

Movies (Filmes):

```
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]  
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string NomeFilme { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ator> atores { get; set; }
```

Actors (Atores):

```
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Filme> filmes { get; set; }
```

Now, i'm initializing the DB with some values. The movies table has this:

```
    var filmes = new List<Filme> {
            new Filme {   
                NomeFilme = "Harry Potter - Part II",
            }
        };
```

And the actors table has:

```
    var lista = new List<Ator> {
            new Ator {   
                Nome = "Emma Watson"
            },
            new Ator {   
                Nome = "Daniel Radcliffe",
                filmes = GetMovies()
            }
        };
```

So, what I'm doing should be creating a HarryPotter movie and adding 2 actors. Radcliffe should have Harry Potter in his movie list.

The first problem i find is that I'm getting 2 HarryPotter movies in my movie table. I'm guessing its because I'm calling "filmes = GetMovies()", and the function creates the movie again. I thought maybe i had to use the DB ProductContext and something like

```
        context.Filmes.ElementAt(0)
```

But I'd still have to do a "new list" and when i tried it, i got an exception. So, my 1st question would be:
How do I add movies to my Actors and Actors to my movies without duplications? (do i have to do it like SQL and create a new table? O.o)

---

Second of all, somewhere in my webpage, im trying to access these values. Even with the duplication, i tried something like this:

```
        IQueryable<Ator> temp = _db.Atores;
        foreach (var t in temp)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("actor:" + t.Nome);

            foreach (var p in t.filmes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("OMFG IT WORKED " + p.NomeFilme);
            }
        }
```

Now after i print the actor's name, 
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

I can't find more info about what's causing it. Am i accessing something wrong? Why does it work for the actor, but crashes for the movies? I'm feeling quite lost!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do I add movies to my Actors and Actors to my movies without duplications?"

I did it like SQL, another table with MovieIDs and ActorIDs. I ignored the Virtual IColletions and just had ints pointing to those IDs.

--

With this new method, iterating across the values gets a lot easier, but i still had some trouble selecting values into my Iqueriable to return to my ASPX pages. The easy way i found was just to convert every IQueriable to a list (with .toList() ) and work from there. Works like a charm!